# Dispatch.Invoke( new Action...) with a parameter

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading

Previously I had

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => colorManager.Update()));
```

to update display to WPF from another thread. Due to design, I had to alter the program, and I must pass ColorImageFrame parameter into my ColorStreamManager.Update() method.

Following [this](http://blog.decarufel.net/2009/03/good-practice-to-use-dispatcher-in-wpf.html) link, I modified my dispatcher to:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action<ColorStreamManager, ColorImageFrame>((p,v) => p.Update(v)));
```

It compiles fine but would not run at all. VS2010 says **"Parameter count mismatch."** In my `ColorStreamManager.Update()` method I have
`RaisePropertyChanged(() => Bitmap)`;

Could someone point out where did I go wrong?

The signature of `ColorStreamManager.Update()` method is the following:

```
 public void Update(ColorImageFrame frame);
```

Comment: What does the declaration of `ColorStreamManager.Update` look like?

Comment: I updated my question to answer your question

Comment: @ikel We don't really need to see the whole function, just the signature of the method.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You don't want the action to have parameters, because the `Dispatcher` isn't going to know what to pass to the method.  Instead what you can do is close over the variable:

```
ColorImageFrame someFrame = ...;
Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => colorManager.Update(someFrame)));
```

Comment: Ah! _"close over the variable"_ I needed that piece of information!

Answer (score 3):

If you call `Invoke` with an `Action<T1, T2>` delegate, you need to pass the two Action parameters to the Invoke call:

```
ColorStreamManager colorManager = ...
ColorImageFrame frame = ...

Dispatcher.Invoke(
    new Action<ColorStreamManager, ColorImageFrame>((p,v) => p.Update(v)),
    colorManager,
    frame);
```

The Invoke overload you're using here is [`Dispatcher.Invoke(Delegate, Object[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc647509.aspx).

Comment: It's both easier and cleaner syntactically to just close over the variables instead of passing them in this way.

Comment: But it doesn't work under all circumstances. Capture of the outer variables differs from explicitly passing them to Invoke. See for example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/271447/1136211). Moreover OP has explicitly asked for this solution.

Comment: That's not applicable here because `Invoke` is synchronous; it won't return until after the delegate has been run, and it is never run after the method returns.  Now if this was using `BeginInvoke` then there are potential issues with closure semantics if you aren't careful.  Such issues can *always* be addressed by the simple creation of a new local variable to hold a copy, if needed.  As for the OP requesting it, the OP is requesting how to get the object he has to the `Update` method, he never said closures couldn't be used.

Comment: It's required for C# 1.0 when there was no mechanism for closure semantics, or for people used to that method of programming (because they come from a language that doesn't have a mechanism for creating closures), or for those that just prefer it.  It's never *needed*.

Comment: Ok, you're certainly right. But still the reason for the "Parameter count mismatch" error is explained here.